# Android Gallery with Gridview & Thumbnails

Tags: android, gridview, three20, android-gallery

For my App I need a gallery (Gridview) with remote images (URLs of original and thumb are getting parsed by a JSON file) where it shows the thumbnails and on a click it loads the original sized image (async would be best...)
I have seen this on http://fukyo-it.blogspot.com/2010/08/iphone-sdk-creating-photo-gallery-with.html for the iPhone but how is this easily acheivable on Android?

Thanks alot for helping!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This looks like the perfect library for my needs: https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader

Answer (score 0):

I haven't done any iPhone development, but this shouldn't be too hard on Android.  I would follow the tutorial here http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-gridview.html.  I did something similar utilizing the Gallery control instead.  The main issue I hit was around performance and memory, so make sure to download the images on a background thread, and throttle how many images you keep in memory if its going to be a large set of images.